# How to add multiple row input fields when clicking on button a row to be added?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

I am designing an invoice in which multiple product entry should be done 
here in which the js code I have written for the cloning is:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount<200){
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    row.id = 'row_'+rowCount;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].outerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
             }
      var listitems=row.getElementsByTagName("input")
        for (i=0; i<listitems.length; i++) {
          listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('"+row.id+"')");
            }
        }
    }


</SCRIPT>
```

by using the above function, cloning is possible. But for every new row the id and names to be changed or else it is not saving

My html code is:

```
<!-- Form Name -->
<legend align="center">Purchase invoice</legend>
<div>
<table align:"left" width="300">
<tr>
<td >
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="date">date</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
<input id="date" name="date" placeholder="date" class="form-control input-md" type="date">

</div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="invoiceNo">invoiceNo</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
<input id="date" name="invoiceNo" placeholder="invoiceNo" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

</div>
</div>
<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="vendorname">Vendor name</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
<select id="vendorName" name="vendorName" class="form-control">
     {{# each items }}


    <option> {{ this.vendorName}}</option>
       {{/each}}

</select>
</div>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>


<INPUT type="button" value="Add Product " onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<table class="table table-hover" >
<thead>
   <tr>
       <td>productno</td>
       <td>productName</td>
       <td>size</td>
       <td>colour</td>
       <td>quantity</td>
       <td>costprice</td>
       <td>MRP</td>
       <td>amount</td>
       <td>discount%</td>
       <td>discount value</td>
       <td>net amount</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
</table>


<TABLE id="dataTable" class="table table-hover" >
    <TR id='row_0' name="row0">

  <p>

    <td>

    <input id="orderNo" name="orderNo" placeholder="productno" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
  </td>

<td>
         <select id="productName" name="productName" class="form-control-md">


              {{# each items }}


               <option value="{{ this.productid}}"> {{ this.productname}}</option>
                  {{/each}}

     </select>

     </td>
     <td>
          <select id="size" name="size" class="form-control-md">
           {{# each items }}


            <option > {{ this.size}}</option>
               {{/each}}


         </select>

     <!-- Text input-->
   </td>
   <td>
       <select id="colour" name="colour" class="form-control-md">
         {{# each items }}


          <option > {{ this.colour}}</option>
             {{/each}}


       </select>
   </td>
   <td>
     <input id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control " type="text">

  </td>
   <td>
     <input id="costPrice" name="costPrice" placeholder="costPrice" class="form-control" type="text"  onChange="calculate()">

   </td>
   <!-- Text input-->
   <td>

     <input id="mrp" name="mrp" placeholder="mrp" class="form-control" type="text">
   </td>
   <td>

   <td>
     <input id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="amount" class="form-control" >

   </td>
   <td>
     <input id="discount" name="discount" placeholder="discount%" class="form-control"type="text">

   </td>
   <td>

      <input id="discountvalue" name="discountvalue" placeholder="discountvalue" class="form-control"type="text">

    </td>
    <td>
     <input id="netamount" name="netamount" placeholder="netamount"  class="form-control"type="text">

   </td>
       </tr>
       </p>

  </tbody>
  </table>

 <table>
 <!-- Text input-->
 <td>
 <label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="advance">Advance</label>
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <input id="advance" name="advance" placeholder="Advance" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

 </div>



 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="Tax">Tax</label>
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <select id="Tax" name="Tax" class="form-control">
  <option value="14.50">14.10</option>
  <option value="12.50">12.50</option>
 </select>
</div>
</div>
 </td>
 </table>
 </table>

 <label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="netTotal">netTotal</label>
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <input id="netTotal" name="netTotal" placeholder="netTotal" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

 </div>

 <label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="subTotal">SubTotal</label>
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <input id="subTotal" name="subTotal" placeholder="subTotal" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

 </div>

<label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="grandTotal">grandTotal</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<input id="grandTotal" name="grandTotal" placeholder="grandTotal" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

</div>


 <label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="due">due</label>
 <div class="col-md-4" align="left">
 <input id="due" name="due" placeholder="due" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

 </div>


 <!-- Button -->

 <div class="form-group" align="bottom">
 <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="vadd"></label>
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <button id="iadd" name="iadd" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
 </div>
 </div>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

So while adding a row the entire row elements I am saving in an array for multiple products it is not saving I think that the cloned row elements name and id to be changed

Comment: This is not a `node.js` nor a `express` question